# Python CSV Compare two files?

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files.

Say one goes

> Bob|Address|AA22 XXX

Say second goes

> |AA22 XXX|32MPH

How do i make the code check both files and see they both have `AA22 XXX` in and make it create a new file with all the information in?

```
 print ("Here is the list of speeding cars")
    for i,x in zip (Speeding_Cars,Valid_Number_Plates):
        print (i,x)
        with open ("Cars.csv","w")as f:
            f_csv = csv.writer(f)
            writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter = ",")
            writer.writerows(zip(Speeding_Cars,Valid_Number_Plates))


    f1 = ("Data.csv", "r")
    f2 = ("Cars.csv","r")
    f3 = ("Results.csv","w")
    c1 = csv.reader(f1)
    c2 = csv.reader(f2)
    c3 = csv.writer(f3)

    if f1[3] == f2[2]:
        writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter = ",")
        writer.writerows(zip(f1 , f2))
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. I suggest you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then come back and edit this question to make it answerable.

Comment: I don't know how to put it.

Comment: Start by adding some sample input files and their desired output.

Comment: Just edited it hopefully makes more sense

Comment: Now add the code that you've tried. it doesn't matter if it works or not, or even if it causes an error, just show people that you've at least attempted to solve this problem on your own.

Comment: @pzp Ok done a bit of code but i not really meant to add much as its course work for GCSE

Comment: There is no magic method that will compare the CSV files for you.  You have to read the files, store the information in appropriate data structures, and look for the speeders in the list of licenses yourself.  Start by trying to read the data into your program.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, slurp your licences data in a dictionary, indexed by the plate
number

```
with open('licences.csv') as f:
    ls = {plate:[name, addr] for name, addr, plate in  [line.split('|') for line in f]}
```

Then it's the turn of the tickets,

```
with open('tickets.csv') as f:
    ts = [line.split('|') for line in f]
```

Eventually we can join our data and write the results in a file

```
with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(['|'.join(ls[plate]+[plate, speed]) for plate, speed in ts]))
```

---

PS *join* in *join our data* and `join` in the code are two quite different things...

Comment: File "E:\A453\Task 3\Program.py", line 168, in <module>
    MainMenu()
  File "E:\A453\Task 3\Program.py", line 24, in MainMenu
    SpeedTrap()
  File "E:\A453\Task 3\Program.py", line 55, in SpeedTrap
    CarSpeed(Measurement_Use)
  File "E:\A453\Task 3\Program.py", line 148, in CarSpeed
    ls = {plate:[name, addr] for name, addr, plate in  [line.split('|') for line in f]}
  File "E:\A453\Task 3\Program.py", line 148, in <dictcomp>
    ls = {plate:[name, addr] for name, addr, plate in  [line.split('|') for line in f]}
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @ThomasLucas The error you've got means that when you split a single line of your file, using `'|'` as a separator, you obtain a list containing a single item instead of the three items that you are expecting. Why does this happen? I don't know... Check your input file for lines that do not conform to the pattern `name|address|plate` that _you_ have described in your question.